# How do I access the commands of a wsdl thru powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-services

I've noticed that using this script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$id = "idofadmin"
$pw = 'Admin123password'
$wsdl = "https://siteofwsdl.dom.com/services/MainService?wsdl"
$p = New-WebServiceProxy –Uri $wsdl
$p|Get-Member
$p.GetEntityFields(96)
```

Returns all the properties of the wsdl. However, using the $p.getEntityFields command(and all others) keep returning an error of "Cannot find overloaded argument" type of error. The site has this to say about the getEntityFields command.

```
<xs:element name="getEntityFields">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="sessionId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
   <xs:element name="entityTypeId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="mode" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The site also provides this example of a soap request that would normally pull the entity data-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <ser:getEntityFields>
    <ser:sessionId>F0C6EDD44B270B1F3DD0F1492A2A1585</ser:sessionId>
    <ser:entityTypeId>96</ser:entityTypeId>        
    <ser:mode>1</ser:mode>
   </ser:getEntityFields>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What do I need in powershell to make a proxy request to the getEntityField command? I'm guessing something like p.getEntityFields with the parameters of sessionID, the 96 since it's the particular one I want, and mode type 0 since I only want to "read" it. If that's right-how can I get the session ID?
By the way, the output of the soap version the site uses is 
Response (partial)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

   <soapenv:Body>

      <ns:getEntityFieldsResponse xmlns:ns="http://services" xmlns:ax21="http://objects.services/xsd">

         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:ObjectMethod" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <ax21:defaultValue xsi:nil="true"/>

            <ax21:fieldLength>0</ax21:fieldLength>

            <ax21:fieldSubTypeId>0</ax21:fieldSubTypeId>

            <ax21:fieldTypeId>1</ax21:fieldTypeId>

            <ax21:isRequired>false</ax21:isRequired>

            <ax21:label>Alternate Resource</ax21:label>

            <ax21:method>alternateResourceId</ax21:method>

            <ax21:methodId>1131</ax21:methodId>

            <ax21:onInsert>true</ax21:onInsert>

            <ax21:onSelect>true</ax21:onSelect>

            <ax21:onUpdate>true</ax21:onUpdate>

            <ax21:sequence>0</ax21:sequence>

         </ns:return>

         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:ObjectMethod" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <ax21:defaultValue xsi:nil="true"/>

            <ax21:fieldLength>0</ax21:fieldLength>

            <ax21:fieldSubTypeId>0</ax21:fieldSubTypeId>

            <ax21:fieldTypeId>1</ax21:fieldTypeId>

            <ax21:isRequired>false</ax21:isRequired>

            <ax21:label>Alternate Resource</ax21:label>

            <ax21:method>alternateResourceByTitle</ax21:method>

            <ax21:methodId>1160</ax21:methodId>

            <ax21:onInsert>true</ax21:onInsert>

            <ax21:onSelect>false</ax21:onSelect>

            <ax21:onUpdate>true</ax21:onUpdate>

            <ax21:sequence>9999</ax21:sequence>

         </ns:return>

         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:ObjectMethod" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <ax21:defaultValue xsi:nil="true"/>

            <ax21:fieldLength>64</ax21:fieldLength>

            <ax21:fieldSubTypeId>0</ax21:fieldSubTypeId>

            <ax21:fieldTypeId>1</ax21:fieldTypeId>

            <ax21:isRequired>false</ax21:isRequired>

            <ax21:label>Base Calendar</ax21:label>

            <ax21:method>initialBaseCalendarTitle</ax21:method>

            <ax21:methodId>101101</ax21:methodId>

            <ax21:onInsert>true</ax21:onInsert>

            <ax21:onSelect>false</ax21:onSelect>

            <ax21:onUpdate>true</ax21:onUpdate>

            <ax21:sequence>0</ax21:sequence>

         </ns:return>

         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:ObjectMethod" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <ax21:defaultValue xsi:nil="true"/>

            <ax21:fieldLength>6</ax21:fieldLength>

            <ax21:fieldSubTypeId>0</ax21:fieldSubTypeId>

            <ax21:fieldTypeId>6</ax21:fieldTypeId>

            <ax21:isRequired>false</ax21:isRequired>

            <ax21:label>Billable Rate</ax21:label>

            <ax21:method>targetBillingRate</ax21:method>

            <ax21:methodId>1116</ax21:methodId>

            <ax21:onInsert>true</ax21:onInsert>

            <ax21:onSelect>true</ax21:onSelect>

            <ax21:onUpdate>true</ax21:onUpdate>

            <ax21:sequence>0</ax21:sequence>

         </ns:return>
```

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` can help you here. See this example: https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/getting-started-soap-based-web-services-and-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer this question thru some trial and error-if there is extra code here, let me know and I can remove it. But the following does work for the wsdl i'm trying to access. It would seem the xmlsoap and invoke-webrequest are not needed here, as everything starting at the new WebServiceProxy is what we really want to work. The parameters of the commands are actually requested should you enter the command without any (). PowerShell gives you the list of expected data types-forcing me to use type [ref] when needed.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$id = "idoflogin"
$pw = 'adminpw'
$wsdl = "https://site.dom.com/services/MainService?wsdl"
$p = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdl -Credential $creds -Namespace Proxy 
$sessionD = $p.login($id, $pw, $false, $false)
$p.getEntityFields($sessionD, '96', '0', '1', '0')
$p.logout($sessionD, [ref]$false, [ref]$false)
```